# I get "Process finished with exit code 0" instead of expected output

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to coding in Python and I starting writing my own program. Things don't work and I'm having great difficulty understanding why.

I've tried changing my variables from global to class to everything under the sun and it's still bugs. I've also went through my code many many times but I kind of feel as if I'm just throwing together random things.

This code is supposed to ask for your name then ask for your height, weight, shape-size and shoe-size. It should have a function for each variable which asks the user for their information then at the end of the code it should state that persons name then state their other information back to them. ex

> hello Jimmy! Your Height is 5'6" your weight is 180 lbs your shirt-size is medium and your shoe-size is 10.

My code:

```
name = input('What Is your Name?')
print('Hello' + name + '!')

# This is the next part in the code
class Information:
    global name1

name1 = Information()
height2 = Information()
weight3 = Information()
shirtSize4 = Information()
shoeSize5 = Information()

n = name1
h = height2
w = weight3
sh = shirtSize4
ss = shoeSize5
i=int

def n() : (h,w,sh,ss)


def h(): int(input('Please Enter Your Height'))
if h == i(4):
    print("Please provide a Height larger than 4 feet")
else:
    print(h)

def w() : i(input("Please Enter Your Weight in number of pounds, ex(100)"))
if w == i(90):
        print("There is now way you're under 90 lbs. Please Enter A different weight")
def sh() : i(input("Please Enter your Shirt Size"))

def ss() : i(input("Please enter Your shoe size"))

if ss == i(3):
    print('Please Enter a shoe size larger than an infant thank you.')
else:
    print(ss)

#in the next line i'm trying to print out a string with variables 
def print():
    ("Hello" + n + '! Your Height is' + h + "Your Weight is" + w + "Your Shirt-Size is"+ sh + "and your ShoeSize is" + ss)
```

And the result:

```
What Is your Name?Zack
HelloZack!
<function h at 0x02D09C48>
<function ss at 0x02D09D20>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is what comes up instead of input questions.

Comment: Your code sample is not indented properly. Can you fix the indentation first? From the output that you described, I would say that all your code logic are placed inside functions and these are not being called in your script. You only defined the functions, but you need to call them as well in order to access the logic that you assigned.

Comment: "I kind of feel as if I'm just throwing together random things" => that's indeed the case obviously, and this is a well known antipattern (google for "programming by accident" or "programming by permutations").  The good news is that you're aware of it, so you have a chance to fix this. The less good news is that you obviously don't yet fully grasp some basic programming concepts (functions, classes etc), and explaining those is way beyond the scope of stackoverflow. I strongly suggest that you start with some beginner programming tutorial AND the official Python tutorial.

Comment: I'm not sure how the indentation should look like, when I try to make it look uniform it reacts poorly(coming up with errors). It's been difficult to understand the difference when so many people have different programming styles which makes it difficult to understand from this.

Comment: I have tried to add a useful title to this to encourage readers to help. zman, if you have a better way of describing the problem, please feel free to edit it again.